# inverse transform throws error in LSTM prediction

Tags: python, scikit-learn, transform, lstm, valueerror

I am having a LSTM which will predict the  value for the next timestep .So my inputs are scaled into the LSTM like below:

```
test_X = reframed.values
test_X = test_X[:test_X.shape[0], :]
scaler = PowerTransformer()
test_X = scaler.fit_transform(test_X)
test_X = test_X.reshape((test_X.shape[0], 1, test_X.shape[1]))
print(test_X.shape)
```

> (1, 1, 17)

Then I predict like below :

```
yhat = model.predict(test_X)
```

And I have a value for that .

Now I want to inverse scale it so I apply

```
inv_yhat = scaler.inverse_transform(yhat)
```

But this throws an error like below :

> ValueError: Input data has a different number of features than fitting
>   data. Should have 17, data has 1

Not sure why is this error throwing when the model already predicted the value but just inverse scaling is left.

EDIT :

I use the scalers like this in my training

```
scaler_x = PowerTransformer()
scaler_y = PowerTransformer()
train_X = scaler_x.fit_transform(train_X)
train_y = scaler_y.fit_transform(train_y.reshape(-1,1))
test_X = scaler_x.fit_transform(test_X)
test_y = scaler_y.fit_transform(test_y.reshape(-1,1))
print(train_X.shape, train_y.shape, test_X.shape, test_y.shape) 



import joblib
joblib.dump(scaler_x, 'scaler_x.gz')
joblib.dump(scaler_y, 'scaler_y.gz')
```

Then I scale my new fetaures like below :

```
scaler = joblib.load('scaler.gz')
test_X =scaler.transform(test_X)
```

still throwing the same error.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to do the inverse transform on your y data when you only applied the transform to the x data. The difference in the number of features (17 for x; 1 for y) is why you get that error

EDIT:

You need to create separate scalers for your x and y data e.g.

```
scaler_x = PowerTransformer().fit(test_x)
scaler_y = PowerTransformer().fit(test_y) # can be any transformer
scaled_test_x = scaler_x.transform(test_x)
scaled_test_y = scaler_y.transform(test_y)
```

Then when you want to make a prediction from your fitted model:

```
yhat = model.predict(test_x)
inv_yhat = scaler_y.inverse_transform(yhat)
```

Comment: because for training the model I transform both X and Y but in real-time I will not know y so how do I change it back to  the correct one.like scaled X input gives the not scaled Y ?  in other words "How to make real world predictions with model trained on Standardized/Scaled data?"

Comment: this works for training the model but on real Time there is no test_y  which is my case

Comment: I used test_y because you used it in your code. You can equally replace it with train_y, then when your model makes a prediction from transformed x data, you can apply the inverse transform to the predicted y data to get the unscaled Y

Comment: I updated my question so I do use two scalers already but now I have to save them and use it like below : `import joblib
joblib.dump(scaler_x, 'scaler_x.gz')
joblib.dump(scaler_y, 'scaler_y.gz')`   Is it ?

Comment: It should be `joblib.dump(scaler_x, 'scaler_x.save')` and `joblib.dump(scaler_y, 'scaler_y.save')` . Then you just need to use `joblib.load('scaler_y.save')` to load in your scaler

Comment: And then should it be `scaler = joblib.load('scaler_y.save')
inv_yhat =scaler.inverse_transform(yhat)` or `scaler = joblib.load('scaler_y.save')
inv_yhat =scaler.transform(yhat)`

Comment: You've got the loading correct, then you should use `inv_yhat = scaler.inverse_transform(yhat)`